# Extract word with regex except if it is a given word

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match and extract part of an URL with regex, except if it is a given word.

Here is some test data which already works:

```
/api/add             --> no match
/api/add/view        --> no match
/api/user1           --> matches and extracts "user1"
/api/user1/profile/  --> matches and extracts "user1"
```

Not working:

```
/api/aaa/profile/  --> matches and extracts "aaa"
```

Here is the current regex I have:

```
/^\/api\/(?:([^\/(add)]+?))\/.*?$/i
```

I works as I want except if it contains "a" or "d" instead of the entire "add" word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
/^\/api\/(?!add(?:\/|$))([^\/]+)/i
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aZEG15/1)

In your regex when you use `[^\/(add)]+` that means any character except any of `/`. `(`, `a`, `d`, `)` characters because inside character class i.e. `[...]` there is no grouping.

Comment: This does not return the first segment after "api" in the first capturing group.

Comment: That is exactly it does, check demo link and captured groups under `MATCH INFORMATION` section.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to match "/api/*/whatever" and return what was found for * unless it's "add"

```
/^\/api\/(?!add\b)(\w+)(?:\/\w+)*\/?$/i
```

Comment: It is unspecified if /api/add-on should be a match or not.

Comment: `/api/add-on` or `/api/address` won't match